# Dispatching an action isn't setting redux with result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been struggling with this for the past 18 hours and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have redux setup and I have it dispatching actions and receiving state correctly for other components but in one component I want to dispatch an action on click, which then calls an api and sets the app state in redux with the results of the api.

But it's just not returning anything. I can manually set the payload with a string if I hard code that in so I know the action is getting fired ok. I've also checked that the api is working fine and I've even tried replacing the api with jsontypicode dummy results to see if that makes a difference, it doesn't. Can any one please HELP point me in the right direction??

Here's my code.

ACTION:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { SET_POSTS } from "./types";

export const setPosts = () => dispatch => {
    axios
        .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`)
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data,
                settingCorrect: true
            })
        )
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: {}
            })
        );
};
```

REDUCER:

```
import { SET_POSTS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    loading: true,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){

    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case SET_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: payload,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

APP:

```
    selectUnit = (e,unit) => {
            this.props.setPosts();
            this.props.setHistoricalData(unit);
    };

   ....

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setPosts: () => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'SET_POSTS',
            })
        },
        setHistoricalData: (history) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_HISTORICAL_DATA'
            })
        }
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts);
```

Comment: It looks like you're not actually passing any post data in `setPosts`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're just not using the action create in `mapDispatchToProps`. If I understand your architecture correctly, the following would be a correct `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setPosts: () => {
            dispatch(setPosts())
        },
        setHistoricalData: (history) => {
            dispatch(getHistoricalData(history))
        }
    }
};
```

While remembering to import your action creator functions.

Comment: Not quite sure if `setHistoricalData` is correct because you didn't share that action creator. You likely need to pass `history` to it.

Comment: Thank you. I can not believe that but I forgot to import the action!

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us!